# What does "cooking bacon" mean?

Tags: bacon

Does that mean the bacon is already cooked? (you can eat directly from the package)
Or do I still need to cook the bacon?
I bought a bacon that has no instructions on the package, but it also mentioned that it needs to be stored on cold temperature

Comment: Are you saying that the product is actually called cooking bacon? I've not heard of that. Can you post a picture?

Comment: @Cindy I'm not sure what you meant but that's misleading. Sliced ham (as you'd put in sandwiches) is a very similar product that needs to be refrigerated despite being cooked and ready to eat.

Comment: @Cindy I believe I've seen a similar product here, very rarely. But the existence of cooked bacon products that can be kept at room temperature doesn't lead to your conclusion (even if you'd specified the "fully cooked bacon" in your original comment).

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to add more details? Maybe a photo of the package (or even a link to the product in an online supermarket)

Answer (score 1):

"Cooking" doesn't mean "cooked". It can be read as either "in the process of cooking", which is clearly nonsense here, or "for cooking", which makes sense for a raw product.

When you say "a bacon" do you mean one large piece? This might also be called a bacon joint or gammon joint. Or do you mean a pack of slices (rashers)? The latter are quicker and easier to cook: grill or fry until they look done. The former will need you to [calculate the cooking time based on weight](https://www.lovepork.co.uk/how-to-guides/gammon-ham/cooking-gammon/) whether you roast it, boil it, or boil first before finishing in the oven.